# "Unlike many other languages, you cannot [skipped]" - Is it OK to use such a construction?

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality, sentence-choice

I have a text about German language. There is a following sentence:

> In German, unlike many other languages, you cannot [skipped].

Is it grammatically correct to omit "In German"?

> Unlike many other languages, you cannot [skipped].

I'm not sure the second variant is correct because it looks to me as I'm talking about the language itself (like "Unlike many other languages, German has a very strong emphasis on [skipped]").

Or maybe the best possible option would be the following one?

> Unlike many other languages, you cannot [skipped] in German.

Comment: If you omit "in German", what does "other" exclude?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the meaning of “other languages” is clear from context, then the second variant is valid, but if there is any possible ambiguity, I’d go with the first or third variants.